# Realm iOS Swift Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Keychain returned unexpected status code: -25299' i

Tags: ios, swift, realm

This Happen in this part of the code

```
let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "Manoj", password: "123456")
SyncUser.logIn( with: credentials,
                server: Constants.AUTHURL,
                onCompletion: { [weak self] (user, err) in
    if let error = err {
        // Auth error: user already exists? Try logging in as that user.
        debugPrint("Login failed: \(error)");
        return;
    }
    guard let self = self else { return }
    if self.checkUserAllReadyExists() {
        self.notificationRegister()
        return
    }
})
```

is the constant auth is the server instance URL
1. Realm version of the 5.0.1
2. Xcode 11.5
3. Real Device - iPhone XR 13.5

Note:- issue found only with the device

Comment: Which specific line is the error occurring on?

Comment: SyncUser.logIn( with: credentials,
                server: Constants.AUTHURL,
                onCompletion: { [weak self] (user, err) in

Comment: You may want to step through your code as there's nothing in that line that would throw an error related to the keychain - unless you've somehow tied Constants.AUTHURL to it. Add a breakpoint and check again.